# cannot rename name apps of cli in heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I´m trying to rename apps of cli, but I get the error, that No app specified.

I done

```
heroku create
heroku apps:rename newname
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says: run this command from an app folder.
To do this you have to clone the app first. Then go into the app folder and run your command again.
**Or** just specifiy the app via --app oldname:

```
heroku apps:rename newname --app oldname
```

Comment: I done git clone url, but I received one error 502 that can not cloned